# Discord js - Fetch Guild role list (array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

### Trying to get roles from a discord server with discord.js

I started playing around with Discord bots using the discord.js library.

One of my objectives was to get the Guild roles in an array. I figured out a way to get it, but it is returning an array inside another array:

```js
    const roles = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => {
        return guild.roles.cache.map(role=>role.name);
    });

    console.log(roles);
```

This is returning:

```
[ [ '@everyone', 'Demi God', 'Bot', 'God', 'Test' ] ]
```

I figured that there should be a better way? I figured I could also deconstruct the array but wanted to know if there was something I missed first.

Comment: Because you're using a `map` inside a `map` and both returning an array. What do you want to return? A single array with all the roles in every guild?

Comment: Yes that would be the desired outcome.

Comment: A solution that I found was to create a global `let role = []`  and just push it into that array. but I am not sure that this is the best way to go..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to get a single array.

Using [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array:

```js
const roles = client.guilds.cache
  .map((guild) => guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name))
  .flat();
```

Using [`flatMap()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=flatMap) that will return a single collection of roles, so you'll still need to use `map()` to return an array of role names:

```js
const roles = client.guilds.cache
  .flatMap((guild) => guild.roles.cache)
  .map((role) => role.name);
```

Using [`reduce()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=reduce):

```js
const roles = client.guilds.cache.reduce(
  (acc, guild) => [...acc, ...guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name)],
  [],
);
```

Using [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```js
const roles = [];
client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
  roles.push(...guild.roles.cache.map((role) => role.name));
});
```

If you only want to use the role names, you can use any of these. If you want to use roles, not just their names, maybe `flatMap()` is the best option as it returns a single collection, similar to `guild.roles`.